# Using device fingerprint reader with Open ID Connect

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, fingerprint

We have a number of web services that currently use an OAuth implementation to provide the security layer. As were in the process of creating a native mobile application, we would like to use the devices fingerprint reader to authenticate the user (with the option to fall back to username / password where a fingerprint reader is not available).

Are there any examples of doing this in secure manner?

At present, we challenge the user for some credentials, they provide us with a username / password, we compare this to details that we store in our database, and approve or deny the request.

If we use the fingerprint reader, again, we challenge the user for some credentials. As the application is native, we have access to the devices fingerprint reader. We acquire and validate the finger print and again either approve or deny the request.

The problem I face from a security perspective is that all of the validation happens on the client, we (the identity provider) havent confirmed any details.  My train of thought is that as its a first party client, and the communication channel is appropriately secured (TLSMA in this case). Is this correct? Am i overlooking a fundamental security issue?

Comment: Can't you just have the user create an account (or choose to change their password if they already have one), and then simply update the user's password to be their fingerprint pattern in your database?